# Auth not initialized when route is registered within service provider boot method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Why is Auth not being initialized when the route is registered within service provider boot method?

**SCENARIO 1: Auth is Okay**

web.php

```
Route::get("/user", "UserController@index");
```

User Controller Class:

```
Class UserController extends Controller {
     function index() {
        if(Auth::check()) { // returns true
            // perform action
        } else {
            // redirect here
        }
    }
}
```

**SCENARIO 2: Auth is not initialized**

But when you register the route inside boot of a ServiceProvider Auth::check now is returning false. It seems the Auth properly initialized when called this way.

```
...
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

/*
 * UserServiceProvider
 */
App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class,

],
...
```

User Service Provider Class:

```
class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        Route::get("/user", "UserController@index");
    }
}
```

User Controller Class:

```
Class UserController extends Controller {
     function index() {
        if(Auth::check()) { // returns false
            // perform action
        } else {
            // redirect here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It hasn't being initialized yet because the purpose of the providers is to initialize things

Comment: accounting to Laravel Documentation -
Service Provider - In general, we mean registering things, including registering service container bindings, event listeners, middleware, and even routes. Service providers are the central place to configure your application.

Comment: If this is the case, why register route inside service provider then?

Comment: "Service providers are responsible for bootstrapping all of the framework's various components, such as the database, queue, validation, and routing components. " https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/lifecycle

Comment: You can define route in **ServiceProvider** within the `register` method like said in the [Service Provider Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers#the-boot-method). Normaly It's supposed to work, **due to the fact that every thing which have been define in every register Service Provider will already been define and ready to work**